# Can summations distribute across absolute values?

Tags: summation, absolute-value

Can I distribute a summation as follows?

$$
k\sum_{x \in X} \left| x - b \right| = \left| \left(k\sum_{x \in X}x \right) - \left( k\sum_{x \in X}b \right) \right|
$$

Comment: Your summation ranges over $x\in X$, but the summands are independent of $x$. That does not make sense.

Comment: Have you tried a small numerical example?

Comment: Oh, I made a slight modification. Does it make sense now?

Comment: I've tried a few with holding the inside constant. It seems to work, but I'm afraid of missing a corner case.

Comment: Say, $X=\{{4,6\}}$, $b=5$?

Comment: we will get that  $5=2$  interesting  equality :D.just for joke if we turn over $2$ then it is true

Comment: @dato, I get $2=0$ (if $k=1$).

Comment: aa you mean that  when  there  is not given  $x$  in second  term,sum of $b$ is zero?.ok no problem

Comment: I don't understand what the $k$ is doing here: if it's negative, then the putative identity equates a negative quantity with a non-negative quantity, except in the degenerate case $X = \{b\}$.  If $k$ is zero, the identity holds trivially.  If $k$ is positive, we can cancel it from both sides.

Comment: Also, could we have some more context, please?  Are $k$ and $b$ arbitrary real numbers (or complex numbers, or...?)  Is $X$ a finite set of real numbers (or...), or could it be infinite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

Let, $X=\{a_1,a_2, \dots a_n\}$

$b > a_i$ , $1 \le i \le (n-k)$ and $b<a_i ,  (n-k)<i\le n$, for $k>1$.

Use your distribution and check out why it fails.

Comment: I think if $b$ is bigger than all members of $X$ OP's equation works. See my comment on the problem for a simple example that breaks the equation.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Edited it. What about now?

Answer (score 1):

We have the triangle inequality $|a+b|\le |a|+|b|$. The equality fails, if $a,b$ have different signs. What you have here is a generalization to more than two summands and hence can in general only be written as inequality, not as equality.